# google analytics pageview for ajax website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

Does google analytics counts the pageviews if the url of the page changes by javascript?

For example. First I open the page `example.com/about`(1 pageview) in the browser, than I click on the link contacts, but instead of redirect, by ajax I pull that page, insert into the body of the page and also edit the url - making it from `example.com/about` to `example.com/contacts` by this way

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

So, the url changes without page refresh. Will google analytics count the second pageview, or it is still one pageview? And if it will not be counted, can I change some options that it will.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is still one pageview. You could add the analytics code in a function add call that function when your url changes.

Comment: Thanks @putvande, maybe will work, will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics cannot count page changes if you use AJAX to load the pages. You need to use the `_trackPageView` function to manually register pageviews every time you change the page via JavaScript. [Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview).

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/home/landingPage']);
```